# Why is my function not printing a value Im trying to make a triangle area calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a triangle area calculator, with the following [program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2zDZ.png):

```py
base=int(input("What is the base"))
height=int(input("What is the height"))

def tri_area(base, height):
    return(base * height)/2
print(tri_area)
```

Why is my function not printing a value?

Comment: You need to pass arguments to your function. Your last line should be `print(tri_area(base, height))`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't supply any arguments to your function, you need to do it like this:

```
print(tri_area(base, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move `height=int (input("What is the height"))` to the new line.

Comment: which line are you reffering to?

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. I didn't check the image. The bug is the `print` statement because of lacking parameters. You should write like this `print (tri_area (base, height))`.